# React-native no bundle URL present on getting started project

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to run react-native on an Iphone simulator via "react-native run-ios" following the getting started guide (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)
on react-native's official website, everything seems fine and the new terminal pops up saying "loading dependency graph, done.". The app starts taking a long time to load then it says "No bundle URL present".

This is not unique for this getting started project. I have tried to clone other react native projects having the same result

**What can cause this to fail on both the getting started projects as well as other projects?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting the build:
1. YOUR_PROJECT/ios/build/,
then I ran the project again by changing the port: 
2. react-native run-ios --port 8080